# Implementing a Deck of Cards in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

So I am trying to create a deck of cards and I am still kind of new to C++ and pointers so I have a few question

So I have `Card` class with `getRank`, `getSuit`, and comparison of two `Card` objects.
They way I'm setting the deck is number 1-13 for the rank and 1-4 for the suit. So it's a simple compare by comparing one Card's rank+suit with another card's rank+suit.

So i initialize and declared the two arrays like this:

```
char Rank[13] = {1,...13};
char Suit[4] = ...
```

and my methods are like this:

```
char* getSuit(){ return Suit; }
char* getRank(){ return Rank; }
int Comp(Card *card) {
    if (rank+suit < card->rank+card->suit)
        return 1;
    else if...
    else ...
}
```

My question is, is it a bad idea to have a char array since i'm only storing integers? 
Later on i plan on converting these numbers to output "Three Spade" which is why i used char.

my other question is, does my get methods look right? The get methods, would it be returning the whole array or a index of the array, which is what I want. And am I using '->' correctly?

I still in the drawing process which is why i only have snippets of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some draft for you to consider and probably build your class upon it:

```
class Card
{
public:
   // TODO: provide suitable constructor...

   enum Suit {Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades};
   enum Rank {A, K, Q, J, _10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2};

   Suit getSuit() { return suit; }
   Rank getRank() { return rank; }

   // TODO: implement setters, etc...

   bool operator==(const Card& c) const
   {
      return rank == c.rank && suit == c.suit;
   }

private:
   Suit suit;
   Rank rank;
};
```

So I suggest you to use enums and use exact comparison criterion to compare two cards.
Similarly you can implement operator> and operator< according to your game rules and logic.

You got the idea...

Comment: @Hovhannes I tried using the enum type but I'm getting errors. Even compiling your code doesn't work. the error is: "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

Comment: @Danny on which line of code you are getting the error? I can compile normally.

Comment: @Hovhannes nevermind. created a new project and tried your code again and it compiled fine. thanks. i have a question though. why do i need a set method though? is it because i need to store it later to create a string representation of the Card?

Comment: @Hovhannes when is do "enum Suit {1, 2, 3, 4};" i get that error back. is it because enum can't take in numbers? (which is why you have underscore for yours?)

Comment: @Danny You need setter methods in case you want to be able to modify your cards after they have been created. If you don’t want that functionality you can initialize Card when constructing and skip the setters.
If it was useful to you feel free to vote up and mark as an answer ;)

Comment: @Danny Yes, enum Suit {1, 2, 3, 4}; is not a valid C++. You can’t have numbers in enum. Think of what is in enum as a name(which has also integer representation). Underscores are used to create names for the card ranks. Try to use enums for suit and rank in your code but not integers so code is readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Hovhannes O I see. Still having a bit of a problem though. With this constructor: "Card(Rank r, Suit s);" I try to create a Card object: Card c1(A, Hearts); but i get error C2065: 'A' : undeclared identifier

Comment: @Danny: `Card c1(Card::A, Card::Hearts)`

Comment: @Danny Tomalak is absolutely right ;) +1 for that
You have declared enum types in Card class so you should resolve the names appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

The `->` will obtain the value of the RHS element of the object referenced by the LHS. So yes this is correct as long as you are dealing with pointers on the LHS.

You could look at using Enums for suit.

I recommend looking at your logic for evaluation again as @littleadv has said.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea because it's a waste of space. You only need to store one number, not all of them.

Also, you can implement the `==` operator instead of writing set of methods to do that, it would look more natural to use.

BTW: Re your logic - rank+suit is a criteria for comparison? Rank 9 of suit 4 is better than rank 10 of suit 2? I'm not sure what game it is that you're simulating, but usually the rank precedes the suits... But that depends on the actual requirements, of course, just saying....

Re your questions about using the `->` and the `get` methods - look at the compiler errors when you get them. Yes, in the `get` methods, you return the array. But if you stop using arrays, and only store what you need - then the methods will be fine.

If you want to return string for whatever reason - you can map the integer index you store to the correct string in some static array, so that you won't store redundant strings in different instances of the classes.

Comment: o i forgot to mention. its a poker game but i'm trying to make it simple by making the higher value of the card being greater 3 of diamonds (3+1) is less than ten of spades (10+4). Also, when you say use the == op. where you referring to my compare method? I am required to return -1 0 1 in the compare method and its mandatory to get methods too

Comment: ugh. i misread you comment. rank does precedes the suits. i will fix that

Comment: This doesn't matter.  Cards have no intrinsic values, only those (if any) defined by the game they are used in.  Indeed, for poker, only *hands* have any rank in the problem domain.  If you need an order to work with standard library containers or algorithms, implement any total order you like.

Answer (score 0):

Through this comparison process you will eventually have equal cards... which i guess is wrong...
Edit: also there s a blackjack starter kit in visual studio you can check out.

Comment: i have vs08. do you know where i can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You start to build your class step-by-step with working code. Start with a simple class that only has a `getSuit` and a `getRank` method. Write a little application that tests it, for instance like this:

```
int main() {
    Card card(10, 4);

    if (card.getSuit() != 4) {
        std::cout << "Wrong suit!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

By writing a little test like this for every feature you implement, you make sure stuff works. Also, if you think about how you want to use a class first, you will understand the implementation better.

About the actual implementation, much of it depends on what is taught in your class. One simple thing to consider is to represent ranks and suits using an [`enum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of discriminated union is best handled in languages of the ML family.

For example in OCaml:

```
type suit = Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs | Spades
type rank = Ace | King | Queen | Jack | Num of int
type card = rank * suit
```

Yes I know, the poster requested a C++ answer...

Answer (score 0):

A card is a poor candidate for a class - it has no behaviour, hence no methods.  So it is better modelled as a struct.  Cards are immutable (unless you're cheating), so const member data is indicated:

```
enum Suit {Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades};
enum Rank {A, K, Q, J, _10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2};

struct Card
{
    Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) : suit(suit), rank(rank) {}

    const Suit suit;
    const Rank rank;
};
```

If you can live with the syntax card.first instead of card.suit, you get this for free using the standard pair:

```
#include <utility>
typedef const std::pair<Suit, Rank> Card;

Card aceOfSpades(Spades, A);
```

Bonus: You also get reasonable == and < operators for free.

Answer (score 0):

*Using an interface*

It provides a simple way for students to use cards in the code they write without having access to a
card's internals, without being able to create a specific card, and without knowing how cards are
implemented. This process begins with the code for a card interface, an interface we call ICard.

```
public interface ICard extends Comparable
{
public static final int SPADES = 0;
public static final int HEARTS = 1;
public static final int DIAMONDS = 2;
public static final int CLUBS = 3;
public int getSuit();
public int getRank();
}
```

The interface specifies the behavior of a card without providing information about how cards are
implemented. Once they know that `getSuit()` returns a value like ICard.HEARTS, and that
`getRank()` returns a value in the range of 1 (ace) to 13 (king), students can write code from this
specification. For example, here's code to check whether an array of cards is sorted. We don’t
know how it’s been sorted (e.g., do all the aces come before the twos or do all the spades come
before the hearts?), but we can determine that an array is sorted.
1 Beginning interface names with an uppercase I, followed by a capitalized name, is a common naming
convention in object-oriented programming in many languages, not just Java.

```
public boolean isSorted(ICard[] list){
for(int k=1; k < list.length; k++){
if (list[k-1].compareTo(list[k]) > 0){
return false;
}
}
return true;
}
```

Starting with this simple ICard interface, we can ask students many kinds of
questions to test and review concepts ranging from Java syntax to problem-solving
with respect to one, two, or many cards. Some simple examples are included here,
and more are available on the Web site. In answering these questions students must
understand the interface since there is no implementation. Students focus on
behavior rather than on instance variables and other implementation details, such as
how to create a string to represent the ace of spades.
ICard Study/Code Questions

1. Write the function isRed that returns true if its ICard parameter is red (hearts or
   diamonds) and returns false otherwise.
   public boolean isRed(ICard card){…}
2. A pair is two cards of the same rank (e.g., two kings or two eights). Write the function
   isPair that returns true if its two ICard parameters represent a pair and returns false
   otherwise.
   public boolean isPair(ICard a, ICard b){…}
3. A flush is a hand, say in poker, in which all the cards have the same suit (e.g., five hearts,
   or five clubs for a five-card hand). Write the function isFlush that returns true if the
   array of cards is a flush and returns false otherwise.
   public boolean isFlush(ICard[] hand){…}
4. In blackjack or 21, the value of a hand is the total of the cards, where jacks, queens, and
   kings (11, 12, and 13, respectively, as returned by getRank()) each count as 10, and an
   ace counts as 1 or 10, whichever is better. A total over 21 is a bust; it’s not good to bust.
   Write function handTotal, which returns the total value of a hand.
   public int handTotal(ICard[] hand){…}
   From Interface to Implementation
   The ICard interface provides enough information to write code about cards,
   but there’s no way to create an array of cards, for example, or even a single
   card to test the functions written above (like isPair and handTotal). Where
   do cards come from? In most real-world examples, cards come from a Deck. We’ll
   design a class that models a Deck—which is basically a factory for creating and obtaining cards.
   To keep things simple, and to encourage the study of some standard Java interfaces, the class
   Deck will implement the java.util.Iterator interface. For example, to store all the
   cards from a deck into an ArrayList variable, we can use the following code:

   Deck d = new Deck();
   ArrayList cards = new ArrayList();
   while (d.hasNext()){
   ICard card = (ICard) d.next();
   System.out.println(card);
   cards.add(card);
   }
   System.out.println("# of cards dealt = " + cards.size());

The last few lines output by this code snippet might be as shown below. They will be different
each time because the Deck class developed here shuffles the cards it deals via iteration.
…
ace of spades
jack of clubs
six of spades
ten of hearts
ten of spades
number of cards dealt = 52
If we change the lines after the loop as follows, the output changes as well.

```
Collections.sort(cards);
for(int k=0; k < cards.size(); k++){
System.out.println(cards.get(k));
}
```

System.out.println("# of cards dealt = " + cards.size());
The output shows how cards returned from the Deck class implement the Comparable interface.
…
nine of clubs
ten of clubs
jack of clubs
queen of clubs
king of clubs
number of of cards dealt = 52
The complete code for the class Deck is shown below. The methods hasNext(), next(), and
remove() are required for classes that implement the Iterator interface. The code below
shows how objects of type Card are constructed.

```
public class Deck implements Iterator{
private ArrayList myCardList;
private int myIndex;
public Deck(){
myCardList = new ArrayList();
for(int suit = ICard.SPADES; suit <= ICard.CLUBS; suit++){
for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++){
myCardList.add(new Card(suit,rank));
}
}
shuffle();
}
private void shuffle(){
Collections.shuffle(myCardList);
myIndex = 0;
}
public boolean hasNext() {
return myIndex < myCardList.size();
}
public Object next() {
ICard card = (ICard) myCardList.get(myIndex);
myIndex++;
return card;
}
public void remove() {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}
```

A Deck object stores 52 cards --- these cards can be obtained from a Deck
object via iteration, but a Deck object cannot be reshuffled and re-used.
Instead, a new Deck object must be created to deal new cards. This keeps
things simple and provides an easy-to-follow example of a class that
implements the Iterator interface. The method remove() is optional --- for
the Deck class calling this method throws an exception.
Deck Study/Code Questions

1. Just before the shuffle method is called in the constructor, describe the order of the
   objects stored in myCardList.
2. Describe how each Deck method changes if the instance variable myCardList is changed
   to an array of Card objects, for example,
   private ICard[] myCardList;
   Which choice for myCardList is better? Why?
3. Write client code that defines a Deck object and creates an array of 13 ICard objects that
   represent the spades that are dealt from the Deck. Do this by examining each object dealt
   and only storing the spade cards.
4. Write the body of the hypothetical Hand class constructor specified below

   private ArrayList myCards;
   /**

   - deal numCards cards from d, store in myCards
   - (assume there are at least numCards cards left in d)
     */
     public Hand(Deck d, int numCards){
     }

From Decks to Cards
Our original concern was to use the ICard interface rather than worry about how
cards are implemented. Nevertheless, at some point, there needs to be an
implementation. It's not hard to argue that Card objects should be created by the
Deck class. This is the approach we've used here. The Card class is a private class
declared within the Deck class. There's actually no good reason to declare it within
the Deck (the Deck.java file). However, by declaring it private, we make it
impossible for any code class2 ; it could just as easily be declared as a non-public class within
methods other than the Deck class to construct Card objects. This helps meet our original goal.
Client programs can obtain cards from a Deck, but cannot create cards. Since the Deck supplies
ICard objects, it's not possible to change a card once it's obtained from the Deck since the
ICard interfaced doesn't support modification of a card.

As written, the private Card class defined within the Deck class doesn't support
modification either since its private state instance variables are final, but this is extra
protection that's likely not needed since no client code has access the private Card class.
2 Typically classes declared within another class often make reference to the enclosing object's state. In this
case the nested class Card is declared as a private static class, so it can't reference private non-static state
within a Deck object. The Card class could reference static Deck state, but there is none in this code.
The Card class is available on the Web site; we're not including it here since its implementation
isn't directly related to our discussion about design.
A careful reader might claim that our original goal hasn't been met. Client code can cheat, for
example, by creating a Deck object and then dealing cards from this object until an ace of spaces
(or any other card) is dealt. In the current design of the Deck class this is true. However, we
could create a singleton Deck object, in the same way that a single instance of the class Random
is used in the Marine Biology Case Study. Singleton objects are typically created by declaring
constructors so that they're private. In this case the Deck constructor would change from public to
private. Client code obtains a Deck by calling a public getInstance() method, which
returns a private static Deck object stored in the Deck class. The getInstance method
creates this private object the first time getInstance is called.