# Std::pair or create a struct

Tags: c++, struct, std-pair

We have a discussion on using `std::pair` or some own struct for Snake game column and row. 
Do we need to create something like that:

`struct { int row; int col;} ... cell.row, cell.col;`

Or use:

`std::pair<int, int> ... cell.first, cell.second;`

Comment: Are you trying to create a two-dimensional grid?

Comment: @jkdev yes. what will be look appropriately?

Comment: How about a [two-dimensional array](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson8.html)? Then you could retrieve each element using, for example, `snake_grid[x][y]`.

Comment: @jkdev it was test work [technical task link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JzYnpdRNuGZVhhQ24tSTVHMG8/view?usp=sharing) and this [github link](https://github.com/vityo/SnakePopCap) . 2d array maybe not suit, because we need to find free cell from collection of free places in game (game have cells with walls), so i take set of cells: set<cell_type>. But question is what cell_type must be: my own struct, or we need to use standard pair

Comment: I think either option would work (struct or standard pair). It's not a question of "need"; you could choose one or the other. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260147/3345375 It describes playing cards rather than grids, but the same principles might apply.