# How to implement suit in a Card Game?

Tags: c++

Two players are playing a card game. Each card consists of a rank (from 1 to 13) and a suit (S, H, C, or D). For any two cards, the card with a higher rank is considered of higher value. If they have the same rank, the card with a better suit is considered of higher value. Suit 'S' is better than suit 'H', which is better than suit 'C', which is better than suit 'D'. The input will never contain two cards with the same rank and suit. The output array must contain the card indexes sorted from a higher value to a lower value.
I was able to output the indexes but I can't implement the suit array to the code.

The final output should be {0,4,2,1,3,5}.

P.S. I'm not allowed to include any libraries other than `<iostream>`.
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    int output[6] ;
    int count = 0, max = 0, index;
    int rank[] = {10,7,7,4,10,4};
    char suit[] = {'S','D','C','C','H','D'};
    for(int i=0 ; i< n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            if (rank[j] > max)
            {
                max = rank[j];
                index = j;
            }
        }
        output[count]= index;
        count++;
        rank[index]=0;
        max=0;
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        cout<<output[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Use a class to describe a card.

Comment: A simple rule of thumb is that nouns in your problem description become classes in your code. So you really need a `Card` class, or even a simple `Card` struct. This means that your rank and suit are paired together and so you cannot help but sort them together. This isn't a question of libraries, it's a matter of simple program design.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257801/implementing-a-deck-of-cards-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a Deck of Cards in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257801/implementing-a-deck-of-cards-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved by using class or structures in C++ and implementing custom custom sorter functions.

Have a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct card{

    int rank;
    char suit;
    int index;

}card;

void swap(card *xp, card *yp)  
{  
    card temp = *xp;  
    *xp = *yp;  
    *yp = temp;  
}

bool compare(card c1, card c2){

        if(c1.suit=='S' && (c2.suit=='H' || c2.suit=='C' || c2.suit=='D')){

            return true;

        }else if(c1.suit=='H' && (c2.suit=='C' || c2.suit=='D')){

            return true;
        }else if(c1.suit=='C' && (c2.suit=='D')){

            return true;

        }else if(c1.suit == c2.suit){

            if(c1.rank > c2.rank){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

int main()
{
    const int n = 6;
    card arr[n];

    int rank[] = {10,7,7,4,10,4};
    char suit[] = {'S','D','C','C','H','D'};
    for(int i=0 ; i< n ; i++)
    {
        arr[i].rank = rank[i];
        arr[i].suit = suit[i];
        arr[i].index = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
    { 
        bool swapped = false; 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
        { 
            if (compare(arr[j+1], arr[j])) 
            { 
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
                swapped = true; 
            } 
        } 

        if (swapped == false) 
            break; 
}

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        cout<<"Index: "<<arr[i].index<<" Suit: "<<arr[i].suit<<" Rank:"<<arr[i].rank<<endl;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Index: 0 Suit: S Rank:10
Index: 4 Suit: H Rank:10
Index: 2 Suit: C Rank:7
Index: 3 Suit: C Rank:4
Index: 1 Suit: D Rank:7
Index: 5 Suit: D Rank:4
```

**PS:** The correct order of indices should be {0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5}.